# Can we see the predominance of certain tags along time?

Tags: feature-request

I would like to see the evolution of certain tags along time. For instance, questions involving genetics/biochemistry/DNA had grown, while those involving ecology/zoology/natural sciences declined?

Something like Google Books Ngram Viewer. Is it possible?

Comment: If you reach [25,000 rep](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), you get the the Google site statistics privilege and that may help.

Comment: @AliceD Why so high reputation for this? It's simply out of reach for most users! Even you only have this much in one of your sites.

Answer (score 5):

To query tag popularity or any other public data you can use [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Here is one query, as an example, that can show you the popularity of current top tags over time:
[Top tags today show evolution in the past](https://data.stackexchange.com/biology/query/723468/top-tags-today-show-evolution-in-the-past)

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome!

Comment: @Rodrigo No problem! Let us know of your results!